# Proper way to throw Errors in Dart

Tags: exception, dart, error-handling

Dart provides an `Error` class and an `Exception` class for throwing exceptions. Why doesn't the `Error` constructor take a message parameter like the `Exception` constructor does?

From the [Error class docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Error-class.html):

> Error objects thrown in the case of a program failure.
>
> An Error object represents a program failure that the programmer should have avoided.

From the [Exception class docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Exception-class.html):

> An Exception is intended to convey information to the user about a failure, so that the error can be addressed programmatically. It is intended to be caught, and it should contain useful data fields.

An earlier [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17316538/650894) cites a post confirming this distinction.

I like this distinction. That tells me that many of my checks should throw instances of `Error`.

I'm happy to subclass `Error` with the type of error, but I still need to report values that induced the error. Why is it that Dart makes it easy for me to do this with `Exception` but not with `Error`?

I realize that I can solve the problem by declaring an app-wide error class:

```dart
class AppError extends Error {
  String message;

  AppError([this.message]);

  String toString() {
    return message == null ? runtimeType : "$runtimeType: $message";
  }
}
```

This difference between `Error` and `Exception` has me thinking that I'm misunderstanding `Error` or using it improperly. What's the proper way to throw non-user errors in Dart?

Comment: Possibly it was to discourage directly using `Error` (and you probably shouldn't).  Consider using `AssertionError` via `assert(condition, message)` or `StateError` instead.

Comment: @jamesdlin, aha! I bet that's it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Google shows a total of 42 hits for 'dart "throw StateError"', which doesn't give me much confidence, but this examples page is one of those hits, suggesting that `StateError` is indeed the throwable to use. (`assert()` has limited use because it can't protect state in production.) https://dart.dev/samples#exceptions

Comment: Fair point about `assert()` in release code, although you could throw `AssertionError` directly (or create your own `assert`-like function to do it).  Regarding `StateError`, the low hit count might be misleading since `StateError` is often thrown via other mechanisms (e.g. the [quiver.check](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.check/quiver.check-library.html) functions).

Comment: @jamesdlin, if you'd combine your two comments into an answer, I'd be happy to mark it my preferred answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If anything, it's a mistake that `Exception` takes a message. You should *never* throw a plain `new Exception("message")`.

The difference between `Error` and `Exception` (or really, any non-`Error` thrown object) is that `Error` represents a programming failure.

Your programs should not throw an `Error` as part for normal operation. You should not catch a specific `Error` and react to it. (It's fine for frameworks to catch all thrown objects and log them, in order to keep running, but they shouldn't react specifically to individual errors).
That means that it doesn't actually matter which class you use to represent an error. The only purpose of an error is to be shown to the programmer, so they can fix their bug.
Dart has a number of useful `Error` subclasses which cover most of the situations, and which ensures a fairly *consistent formatting* of the error messages. There is nothing inherently requiring you to use a `RangeError` for an out-of-bounds error, it's just a very convenient helper class, it helps the reader understand what's going on, and we do recommend that you use it.

Use [`ArgumentError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/ArgumentError/ArgumentError.value.html) when an argument to a function does not satisfy the extra (non-type) requirements of it (say, a list must be non-empty).
For number arguments, there is a [`RangeError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/RangeError/RangeError.range.html) for when the number is not in an expected range. For a number intended as an index (like a `list.operator[]` argument), there's even a specialized `IndexError`. They're all there to ensure that you get *consistent* error messages.

If an operation cannot be performed *right now*, because the object is not in a state which supports it, use [`StateError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/StateError/StateError.html).

If an operation cannot be performed by the current object *ever*, use [`UnsupportedError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/UnsupportedError/UnsupportedError.html).

In practice, `StateError`, `UnsupportedError` and `ArgumentError` (and its subclasses) cover the wast majority of runtime errors thrown by user code.
Simply throwing an `Error("message")` is less informative than using one of these, and inventing a new error type is very rarely worth it.

An **exception**, on the other hand, is *intended* to be caught and handled.
It's a message to the caller, at the same level of significance as a return value, and it should contain enough information for the caller to *catch* the specific documented exception that the function might throw, and *react* to that specific exceptional situation.
That's why an exception should, at the very least, have a unique type that allows you to recognize and catch it specifically, and if possible, it should contain any information needed to handle the exceptional situation.

Take `FormatException` which is thrown by various `parse` functions.
It's specific to the operation. It contains available information to help you figure out where the problem is (the input and a position related to the error, mainly for showing to the user since you can't be expected to fix the input.)

Comment: Thank you. I have an additional question: [in the documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling), we can see that code: `throw("some arbitrary error");`. Is it a bad practice to just throw a string? And does this mean that there is something magic that wraps `String` in an `Exception`?

Comment: No, there is *no* magic which wraps anything. You can throw strings. And integers. Any object except `null` can be thrown, but since `String`  is not an `Error`, throwing one is bad for reporting errors, and since it doesn't represent a specific exceptional situation, throwing one is bad for reporting exceptions. So, don't throw strings.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/core/errors.dart

Dart has several predefined Errors that you can instantly use.