Is there a Dart package to give possible uncaught exception warnings?
I'm looking for a package / dart analyzer settings / other solution that would provide VSCode highlighting warnings for when you've used a function that could throw an exception without attempting to catch it.
It would make reviewing code for production env much easier, unless I'm approaching things the wrong way in anyone's opinion? I am under the idea that all expected possible exceptions should be explicitly dealt with, or should be explicitly left to be handled at a higher level or not at all.
I have done some searching on pub.dev and with chatGPT, but haven't been able to find anything that seems to solve the need. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Looking at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315945/error-vs-exception-in-dart
"Except in a few special circumstances, idiomatic Dart should throw Errors, but never catch them. They exists specifically to not be caught so that they take down the app and alert the programmer to the location of the bug." Suggests that ideally a system as I describe shouldn't be needed at all, but I know plenty of cases where I really want to catch and continue operating with functions from libraries that don't always work...

No, but there have been proposals you might find interesting, like adding checked exceptions to the language, or adding a lint to help document exceptions.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
